# On MultiThreading on the Android platform

Tags: java, android

`Multithreading on Android` is to some extent an easy task due to the various possibilities available for us.

However it would be nice to understand the difference between the approaches.

**What is the best way to multitask and based on what preferences is it the "best"?**

1. **`AsyncTask`?**

   ```
   class MultiTasker extends AsyncTask<, , >
   ```
2. **`Runnable`?**

   ```
   Runnable myRun = new Runnable(){
     public void run(){

     }
   };
   Thread T = new Thread(myRun);
   T.start();
   ```
3. **`Handler`?**

   ```
   class MultiTasker extends Handler
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking which one is "best" is the wrong approach here - it depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

1. **Runnable/Thread** - This is the basic, lowest-level ways to control threading in Java.  Provided in the Java APIs, so they're not specific to Android.  You *can* use these in Android programs, but you'll probably want to use one of the other two options for most tasks (or use them *in addition* to `Thread`s).
2. **Handler** - Provided in the Android APIs.  You can `post()` a `Runnable` directly, or `sendMessage()` a `Message` (along with other options, such as providing a delay before processing a `Runnable` or `Message`). However, `Handler` isn't something you would use by itself to provide multithreading - it's use is usually to get *back* into the main activity (UI) thread.  You'd start some other `Thread` to do a process in the background, and inside of it would `post` a `Runnable` using the `Handler` when you needed to update the UI.  Or if you had a task that didn't necessarily need to run in the background, but did need to pop up and do something every so often, you could `post` a `Runnable` with a delay to activate later, and then at the end `post` itself again with a delay.
3. **AsyncTask** - Provided in the Android APIs. This class is for doing something on a background thread, optionally providing incremental updates on the UI thread, and ultimately providing an end result on the UI thread.  The `Params`, `Progress`, and `Result` generic types are used to provide start parameters, progress update data, and end result data, respectively. Internally, `AsyncTask` uses `Thread`s, `Runnable`s, and `Handler`s to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

Its Always better if you go with `AsyncTask()`.. because Thats something which has been built to solve `MultiThreading` issues in Android..